# Generador PDF mediante PHP

Tags: php, html5, css3, phpmyadmin, php8

Tengo este codigo HTML5 con css. Me gustaria saber que al darle a un boton que ponga generar PDF me saque un pdf con la tabla tal y como está, sin que se me destroce. He probado con algunos pero no me respeta el tamaño de la tabla y se me distorsiona. ¿Alguna solucion? Gracias

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    table{
        width: 730px;
        height: 450px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .peque{
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 20px;
    }
    .abajo{
        width: 1px;
    }
    .medio{
        width: -1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9" height="20px">TABLA PRUEBA</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 2 -->
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="9" width="20px">erya</td>
        <td rowspan="6" colspan="3" class="izq">AERGTA</td>
        <td colspan="2" width="2px" class="medio">asegaW</td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="4" width="10px">WERTw</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 3 -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 4 -->
    <tr>
        <td height="15px"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 5 -->
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 6 -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" height="70px"></td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">argae</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 7 -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" height="70px">awsergta</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 8 -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="60px">argar</td>
        <td colspan="2">aergtaer</td>
        <td colspan="3">aswefgt</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 9 -->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="abajo">sdths</td>
        <td colspan="4" rowspan="2" width="20px">dfgh</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="peque" >Hola</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 10 -->
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes añadir [una de estas librerías](https://www.onlinecode.org/open-source-pdf-generation-libraries-php/) a tu proyecto y usarlas para imprimir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar alguna librería como [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) o [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/examples/) aunque si solo imprimirás tal cual la hoja como viene del HTML sin estilos, podría servirte solo añadir un par de líneas en tu HTML antes de la etiqueta `table` agregaremos un boton para imprimir:

```
  <button id="printPDF" onClick="window.print();">Print</button>
```

Después en tu **CSS** agregaremos un hide, para que cuando des click al botón, este no aparezca también al imprimirlo;

```
   @media print { #printPDF { display: none; } }
```

Por último solo configura la salida del documento:

1. Destino Microsoft Print to PDF
2. Diseño Horizontal para que salga la hoja completa
3. Seleccionas **más opciones de configuracion** y despues:
4. **Escala Personalizado** a *200*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá también te dejo el resultado para que lo puedas modificar, si deseas agregar estilos o personalizarlo lo puedes hacer con CSS o bien con una librería, espero te sirva saludos:

[Ver ejemplo](https://codepen.io/synes/pen/wvgRoZv?editors=1111)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono sin problemas